# How to show that this weak scheme is a cubature scheme?

Tags: option-pricing, stochastic-volatility

Weak schemes, such as [Ninomiya-Victoir](https://wiki.duke.edu/download/attachments/9505461/Ninomiya+and+Victoir+-+2008+-+Weak+approximation+of+stochastic+differential+equa.pdf?version=1) or Ninomiya-Ninomiya, are typically used for discretization of stochastic volatility models such as the [Heston Model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heston_model).

Can anyone familiar with [Cubature on Wiener Spaces](http://www.math.hu-berlin.de/~finance/papers/victoir1.pdf) explain why (i.e. with a detailed proof or a reference) these weak schemes can be seen as a Cubature scheme over Wiener Spaces?

Comment: You may try asking this question on mathoverflow.net, it seems to be math-heavy enough.

Comment: Well I 'm affraid that even this is "heavy math" the aim of the forum (in my opinion) is to address this kind of question. MO is more a "pure" math and don't want to pollute it with applicable themes such as Cubature methods in Finance. Regards

Comment: This is certainly on-topic here; it may just be that we don't have enough of an appropriate user-base yet.

Comment: @stonybrooknick : thank's that really helps. Why didn't I thought about that before ??

Comment: @TheBridge Is this question still of interest?

Comment: @ vanguard2k : Yes it is, I think I know now what to prove but I am just too lazy to try to prove it. But if you are willing to do it, I would be delighted to read your attempt. As an indication about what is needed is to prove that moments of the Ninomiya-Victoir scheme matches the moments ot the stochastic iterative (stratanovitch)-integrals. Best regards

Comment: check out my answer to [this question][1] on cubature methods for numerics. 


  [1]: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/373/what-is-a-cubature-scheme/9674#9674

Comment: The following paper gives some indication how a general proof might look: https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/bayerc/files/drifttrick_final.pdf. Starting at the top of page 5, they show how one step in the NV scheme "corresponds to a (non-discrete) cubature formula of order m = 5."

Comment: @ pbr : Thank's I'll take a look. Best regards

Comment: @TheBridge could you answer that question to your satisfaction? If not, I may be interested in looking into it.